# Group theory book recommendation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate student and recently took an introductory course containing properties of  groups, homomorphism, normal subgroups, group action, sylows theorem and a bit about simple groups. Does anybody think starting the book "Finite groups: An introduction" by jean pierre serre be a bad idea with this amount of knowledge ?

Comment: Rotman's book is really good. But, for the beginning, you should start with Dummit-Foote and Artin's algebra.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya What is your view on "Finite groups: An introduction" by jean pierre serre book

Comment: That is a special topic in group theory. That is not for beginning learning group theory. If you are enough comfortable with the complete introductory topics, then you can start J. P. Serre's book.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya What do you think about the book "Groups and representations" by alperin-bell

Comment: I don't know about that. But you can also try the wonderful book Finite Group Theory by Michael Aschbacher. Also, there is a book on representations of finite groups by J. P. Serre.

Comment: I used Dummit-Foote and Artin's algebra. They were good.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try one of the following:

John S. Rose, *[A Course on Group Theory](https://books.google.nl/books/about/A_Course_on_Group_Theory.html?id=pYk6AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)*

Derek J.S. Robinson, *[A Course in The Theory of Groups](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zLfkBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=a%20course%20in%20the%20theory%20of%20groups&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmn7DjwL7YAhVDalAKHU4OAqwQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=a%20course%20in%20the%20theory%20of%20groups&f=false)*

Dummit and Foote, *[Abstract Algebra](http://zeth.ciencias.uchile.cl/%7Ecortiz/Apuntes/ebooks/Abstract%20algebra%20-%20Dummit%20and%20Foote.pdf)*.

Each of these books has a lot of good examples and exercises!

Comment: Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Finite-Theory-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821843443) is also a very nice book at this level, for a reader who is primarily interested in the finite case.